# Use of "mental" and "spiritual" as adjectives

Tags: meaning, word-choice, sentence

If I say something encouraging for someone, then I am **mentally or spiritually supporting** him.

> I mean to input into his head as well as resurect ideas of possibility that has been far out of reach.

Is **mental or spiritual support** the correct term here?

Comment: Please don't ask us to "correct your italic statement". This is off-topic for this SE.

Comment: @StackUnderblow I edited your question to better fit within the EL&U guidelines. If you don't like it, you can roll them back, but it may cause others to close your question as off-topic.

Answer (score 3):

You could certainly say that you're providing both mental and spiritual support, but that phrase sounds quite odd to an English Speaker.

Common phrases to describe doing this for someone includes *bolstering their confidence* or *giving them encouragement.* To bolster means to strengthen.

If you want to be more explicit, you could say something like: "I mean to give him the confidence to reconsider those ideas he gave up on long ago."

Comment: An Excelent quick reply! Thanks a lot.   Admittedly, using English to a non-native to make it sound natural to a native is truly difficult1

Comment: @StackUnderblow I bet! English as a language doesn't really make sense so I guess all you can do is practice and memorize common phrases.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement in italics is overwrought.  To simply say you agree with them should be enough.  If a stronger statement is needed you could say they have your complete agreement or unqualified support.  To go further would be to venture into hyperbole or rhetoric (shudder).

Comment: Thank you.    But to clearify my view, I would like to learn and read English written that way in a correct English manner.